# Lucas Numbers and Phi

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a way to express $L(n)$ in terms of phi? It's part of a problem and I'm really stumped :(. I've already tried L(n)=Phi^n-phi^n, but that was no good. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try using Google. The answer is out there.

Comment: Any sequence satisfying $G_{n+2}=G_{n+1}+G_n$ can be expressed as $a\phi^n +b(-1/\phi)^n$ for some $a,b$.

Comment: But isn't $\phi^n-\phi^n=0$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I'm using lowercase phi to represent \widehat{\phi}. Sorry if it was unclear.

Answer (score 1):

The Lucas numbers $L(n)$ satisfy the same recurrence as the Fibonacci numbers, so $L_n$ can be expressed in the form $A\alpha^n +B\beta^n$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of the equation $x^2-x-1=0$, and $A$ and $B$ are constants.

We can use the fact that $L(0)=2$ and $L(1)=1$ to find $A$ and $B$.